# How to avoid fetching the same data twice in Next.js v13?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I need to lookup an entry from the database and generate the metadata and render the actual page contents.

At the moment, I am doing it like so:

```
export const generateMetadata = async ({
  params: { questionSlug },
}: Props): Promise<Metadata> => {
  const sql = await connectToPostgres();

  const question = await findQuestion(sql, questionSlug);

  if (!question) {
    return {};
  }

  return {
    alternates: {
      canonical: `https://ray.run/questions/${question.slug}`,
    },
    title: question.question,
  };
};

const Page = async ({ params: { questionSlug } }: Props) => {
  const sql = await connectToPostgres();

  const question = await findQuestion(sql, questionSlug);

  if (!question) {
    return notFound();
  }

  // ...
};
```

but this means that I have to make the same database query twice to render the same page.

Is there a way to fetch data once and use it in both methods?

Answer (score 5):

It is not pretty. However, the official way is to use the [`cache` function](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating):

```js
import { cache } from 'react';

const findQuestionWithCache = cache(async (questionSlug: string) => {
  const sql = await connectToPostgres();

  return await findQuestion(sql, questionSlug);
});

export const generateMetadata = async ({
  params: { questionSlug },
}: Props): Promise<Metadata> => {
  const question = await findQuestionWithCache(questionSlug);

  if (!question) {
    return notFound();
  }

  return {
    alternates: {
      canonical: `https://ray.run/questions/${question.slug}`,
    },
    title: question.question,
  };
};

const Page = async ({ params: { questionSlug } }: Props) => {
  const question = await findQuestionWithCache(questionSlug);

  if (!question) {
    return notFound();
  }

  // ...
};
```

The contents of the `findQuestionWithCache` function is only going to be called once per request.

Sadly, the downside of this approach is that `cache` wrapped function cannot be called outside of React/Next.js. Therefore, if you are using the same function outside of your React.js codebase, you have to wrap it locally like I do in the above example. If you only call this function within React.js codebase, then you can probably just wrap the original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js deduplicates fetch requests for generateMetadata but I'm not sure about your database connection. [Good to know section](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#returns)

Comment: It does not do that with database queries. I can see both queries come in.

Comment: You may need to move the database connection to the root layout.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:
By adding the cache object on the topmost.

```
let cache ={};

export const generateMetadata = async ({
  params: { questionSlug },
}: Props): Promise<Metadata> => {
// This if statement return data from cache without send request to server.
if(cache) return cache;
  const sql = await connectToPostgres();

  const question = await findQuestion(sql, questionSlug);

  if (!question) {
    return {};
  }
  cache = question;
  return {
    alternates: {
      canonical: `https://ray.run/questions/${question.slug}`,
    },
    title: question.question,
  };
};

const Page = async ({ params: { questionSlug } }: Props) => {
  
  if (!cache) {
    await connectToPostgres();
    const question = await findQuestion(sql, questionSlug);
    if(!question) return notFound();
  }
  const response = cache;

  // ... use response variable as cache data.
};
```

Comment: This is a hack. Next.js already has [cache support](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching) built in

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem & I only wanted to set the title which seemed like an overkill to re-fetch the data so I opted this workaround (assuming the page is a server component):

```
const Page = async ({ params: { questionSlug } }: Props) => {
  const sql = await connectToPostgres();
  const question = await findQuestion(sql, questionSlug);

  if (!question) {
    return notFound();
  }

  // ...

  return (<>
    ...

    <Script>{`document.title = "${question.question}"`}</Script>

  </>)
};
```

Obviously not an ideal solution but it gets the job done